# REACT - NATIVE BottomSheetFlatList update data error when state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

This is my Code. When I click the times icon on the left, it doesn't delete the data I want. I use [Bottom Sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet), please help me, thank

[without click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaTyj.png)
[when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7V5e.png)

Component

```
  <BottomSelectedRecipient
     onSelect={handleSelectRecipientBottom}
     data={recipientSelected}
     innerRef={bottomSelectedRecipientRef}
  />
```

```
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const colorSchema = useColorScheme();
  const handlePressClose = (id: string) => {
    onSelect?.(id);
  };

  return (
    <AppBottomSheet innerRef={innerRef} snapPoints={['80%']}>
      <View style={tw`flex-1`}>
        <AppTypography
          bold
          textMd
          style={tw`mx-24 dark:text-neutral-0 mt-24 mb-12`}>
          Recipients selected
        </AppTypography>
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          extraData={data}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={tw`flex-row items-center  gap-12 mx-24 py-12 flex-1`}>
                <Avatar
                  size={40}
                  source={
                    item.profileImage
                      ? {
                          uri:
                            process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_S3_SERVER +
                            item.profileImage,
                        }
                      : undefined
                  }
                  title={generateInitials(
                    !item.firstName || !item.lastName
                      ? 'MC'
                      : `${item.firstName || ''} ${item.lastName || ''}`.trim(),
                  )}
                />
                <View style={tw`flex-1`}>
                  <AppTypography
                    bold
                    textMd
                    style={tw`dark:text-neutral-0`}
                    numberOfLines={1}>
                    {`${item.firstName || ''} ${item.lastName || ''}`.trim()}
                  </AppTypography>
                  <AppTypography
                    medium
                    textSm
                    style={tw`dark:text-neutral-400`}>
                    {item.contact?.phoneNumber}
                  </AppTypography>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={tw`w-32 h-32 items-center justify-center`}
                  onPress={() => handlePressClose(item.customerId)}>
                  <CloseIcon
                    size={20}
                    color={
                      colorSchema === 'dark' ? tw.color('neutral-0') : undefined
                    }
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          }}
          ListEmptyComponent={
            <View style={tw`my-24`}>
              <AppTypography
                medium
                textMd
                align={'center'}>{t`no_customer`}</AppTypography>
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    </AppBottomSheet>
  );
};
```

I try this function to clear data

```
  const handleSelectRecipientBottom = useCallback(
    (id: string) => {
      // setFieldValue(
      //   'recipientsList',
      //   values.recipientsList.filter(item => item !== id),
      // );
      const filter = recipientSelected.filter(cus => cus.customerId !== id);
      console.log('recipientsList>>', filter);
      setRecipientSelected(filter);
    },
    [setFieldValue, values.recipientsList],
  );
```

lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem

Comment: Your code example is incomplete and therefore it’s not possible to debug. Make sure the data prop actually updates, causing the flatlist to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this function `handleSelectRecipientBottom` does not listen to `recipientSelected` value, so it's will take the initiateValue, please add `recipientSelected` to dependencyArray then see the difference